# Searching for questions that has ([tag1] or [tag2]) and not [tag3]

Tags: support, bug, tags, search

Ok, I figured out that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+or+iphone-sdk-3.0+or+iphone-5+or+iphone-web+or+iphone-privateapi+or+iphone-4+or+iphone-developer-program+or+ios5+or+iphone-standalone-web-app+or+iphone-web-app+or+iphone-sdk-3.2+or+iphone-softkeyboard+or+iphone-3gs+or+iphone-sdk-3.1+or+iphone-sdk-4.1+or+ios6+or+iphonecoredatarecipes+or+iphone-vibrate+or+iphone-sdk-3.1.3+or+iphone-maps+-iphone) doesn't do what I want. All questions without [iphone] tag but with any of its variants. So I figured that maybe I need to do [`[tag1] [tag3] or [tag2] [tag3]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iphone-5]%20-[iphone]%20or%20[iphone-4]%20-[iphone]%20or%20[iphone-3gs]%20-[iphone]), seems like a good plan... but no joy:

[image]

Its searching for questions tagged with all iphone 3gs to 5 tags, but without iphone, *trice*.

This worked some time in the past, but doesn't work at all now. Can we fix? Or what's the new method